# Would this work as an integral definition?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, definition

I was wondering whether this would work to define $\int_a^bf(x)dx$.

$$\lim_{h\to 0} bh(\sum_{n=a}^\frac bh f(nh))$$

My thinking when I thought up of this formula was to first use a sigma because we have a sum of many values. Then, since we want smaller pieces, I changed it from $f(n)$ to $f(nh)$ to squeeze all the pieces closer together. But so that the biggest value of $f(nh)$ would be $f(b)$, I changed the top value to $b/h$. Then, since we want the average, I multiplied by $h$. of course, that is only the average y value, so I multiplied by $b$ again so that it is $width*height$ instead of just height. If I'm not correct, please explain what I did wrong. Thank you!

Comment: It's not a bad approach, but it can't deal with certain "not-nice" functions (i.e., not continuous). For example, consider the function $$f(x)=\begin{cases}1&x\in\mathbb Q\\0&x\notin\mathbb Q\end{cases}$$The integral (using the Lebesgue definition) of this function from $0\to 1$ is $0$, but your approach would evaluate this integral to $1$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! it is much recommended to check out this link to learn Jax before you ask any question in order to make your question clearer when you write mathematical expressions https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thank you @xX A C E Xx does this look better?

Comment: Your expression
$bh\sum_{n=a}^{b/h} f(nh)$ is only an approximation to $\int_a^b f(x)\>dx$ when $a=0$. Note that $b/h$ is not an integer for most $h$. This should be taken care of as well.